# Как избавиться от постоянных проверок state при одинаковом templateURL angularjs ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-router

Доброго времени. Столкнулся вот с такой проблемой грамотности. У меня есть несколько состояний, которые может принять `$stateprovider`, и все эти состояния имеют одинаковый шаблон (TemplateURL) и являются наследниками, от дефолтного состояния (что бы меньше писать).

Сейчас это выглядит вот так:

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module("StN")
        .config(config);

function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("invoice", {
            url: "/invoice",
            templateUrl: "/Scripts/js/stn/invoice/invoice.html",
            controller: "invoiceController as vm"
        })
        .state("invoice.custom", {
            url: "/castom"
        })
        .state("invoice.search", {
            url: "/search?Status?Invoice?"
        });
}

})();
```

В зависимости от текущего state, должна быть выполнена чуть-чуть другая логика (в данном случае разная фильтрация), это происходит на старте контроллера. 
В данный момент это выглядит вот так

```
angular
    .module("StN")
    .controller("invoiceController", invoiceController);

function invoiceController($http, $state) {
    switch (state.name) {
    case "invoice.search":
        //Одна логика 
        break;
    case "invoice.custom":
        //другая логика
        break;
    case "invoice.status":
        //еще 1 логика
        break;
    }
}
```

Из-за этого возникает проблема, если мне понадобится еще какая-то функциональность, зависящая от текущего `state`, мне придется опять делать такой `switch`.

Помогите пожалуйста сделать этот код более оптимизированным. Спасибо.

Comment: почему не использовать свой контроллер в каждом стейте?

Comment: тут требуется логика этого родительского контроллера. Я так понимаю тут идет намек на наследование. Но я не представляю каким образом делать наследование контроллера в stateprovidr'е

Comment: без [mcve] нельзя сказать на что тут намек идет, и есть ли вообще тут какие-нибудь намеки.

Comment: Исправил, думаю понятна суть

Comment: теперь явно видно, что вместо общего контроллера _invoiceController_ у каждого стейта должен быть свой контроллер, и switch вообще не нужен

Comment: Помимо этого switch есть еще базовая логика контроллера, я ее просто не включал в этот код, т.к. она не сильно связана с этим switch. Мне нужно сохранить все, что есть в этом контроллере

Comment: ну так и убери этот switch, а логику из него разнеси по контроллерам для конкретных стейтов

Comment: Можете пожалуйста показать как унаследовать контроллеры в state, я с этим не сталкивался

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46286/discussion-between-grundy-and-simply-good).

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сделать разные контроллеры под задачи и расширять его базовым контроллером который имеет общую логику с помощью **angular.extend**.
Например:

```
module.controller('searchController', ['$scope', '$controller', function ($scope, $controller) {
    angular.extend(this, $controller('BaseController', {$scope: $scope}));
    // + Дополнительная логика
}]);
```

Comment: Да, я как раз так и поступил, только базовый контроллер реализовал чуть-чуть по другому